# Node App Crashes Due to Empty String as a Password

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

The application works fine if the username or the password is incorrect.

But crashes if the username entered is correct and no password is entered.

> This is the Error I'm getting before the app crashes:
>   Error: Illegal
>   arguments: undefined, string at _async

user.js

```
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) =>{
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
});
```

}

users.js:

```
router.post('/authenticate/user', (req, res, next) =>{
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;
User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User Not Registered'});
    }
    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        if(isMatch){
            const token = jwt.sign({data: user}, config.secret, {
                expiresIn : '6h'
            });

            res.json({
                success: true,
                token: 'JWT ' +token,
                user:{
                    id: user._id,
                    username : user.username
                }
            });
        } else {
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong Password'});
        }
    });
});
});
```

Should I add validation on the front-end of the application for a quick fix or is that not a good idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes..you should add a validation on front-end and also on back-end..try https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix would be to check "candidatePassword" before comparing to hash and if it is empty throw an error.